# Issue Printing from print.css file

Tags: html, css, printing

I'm currently attempting to print from a CSS file that is different than the original and am not able to access the second file. I'm not sure if I have it written incorrectly or maybe placed in the wrong area. I have to use two different files so @print is out of the question. Here is the code, both are placed in the header.

```
<!-- External CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Main Sheet.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Print.css" media="print">
```

Thanks in advance!